# Identifying the right URL to access a database in Java

Tags: java, mysql, database, mysql-workbench

I'm wondering which would be the right path/url to access the "aliens" database I have in my MySQL Workbench.

[image]

[image]

As you can see, the connection name is "new connection_1", the user is "root", and the port is "3306".
Then, I think the database name is aliens.

Until now I've tried this in my eclipse IDE for java:

```
    Connection conn = 
        DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/aliens","root", "myDatabase");


System.out.println(conn);
```

The url is now "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/aliens","root", "myDatabase", but i receive the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/aliens
   at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:702)
   at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:228)
   at EdoardoDatabase.main(MainClass.java:9)
```

Moreover, I would like to print the "connection", nothing else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

YOu'd need a MySql Connector Jar in your classpath and and a Driver set before initiating the connection.

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

You can use maven or download the Driver from Mysql page https://www.mysql.com/products/connector/

Comment: I have personally used a maven project, this has worked.

Answer (score 1):

your Connection String doesn't look bad at all,

your problem is that Java doesn't know to which driver it should map the mysql driver...

if you are sure you have the Mysql jdbc driver on the ClassPath try

```
 Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
```

before you do you getConnection()

this calls the static{} block in the Driver registers the mysql driver for JDBC Connection lookups via the Factory